# I want to search product by pName and pCode with regex,and return only selected values of product array

Tags: mongodb

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("614ace4398294e981cc69053"), "storeId" : ObjectId("614acd4898294e981cc69046"), "product" : [ { "count" : 120, "pCode" : "KL", "pName" : "hat", "pPrice" : 350, "_id" : ObjectId("6151687aa1114528f506d76d") }, { "count" : 500, "pCode" : "J", "pName" : "jeans", "pPrice" : 850, "_id" : ObjectId("6151687aa1114528f506d76e") } ], "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-22T06:33:39.422Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T04:54:56.817Z"), "__v" : 0, "status" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("614b23d0b50f800cf624b0d7"), "storeId" : ObjectId("614acd4898294e981cc69046"), "product" : [ { "count" : 25, "pCode" : "LJ", "pName" : "ladies jeans", "pPrice" : 350, "_id" : ObjectId("614b23d0b50f800cf624b0d8") }, { "count" : 40, "pCode" : "NW", "pName" : "night wear", "pPrice" : 900, "_id" : ObjectId("614b23d0b50f800cf624b0d9") } ], "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-22T12:38:40.059Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-30T12:06:09.727Z"), "__v" : 0, "status" : true }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$regexMatch` into `$filter` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "storeId": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "createdAt": 1,
      "updatedAt": 1,
      "product": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$product",
          "as": "p",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$p.pCode",
                  "regex": "J",
                  "options": "i"
                }
              },
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$p.pName",
                  "regex": "jea",
                  "options": "i"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nAs8KhjTY4f)